# How to call sqlite3_open (passing opaque pointers by reference)

Tags: sqlite, swift

As an exercise, I'm trying to create a wrapper for `sqlite3`.  I've got the bridging header set up, and I can see the tool tips for the `sqlite3` functions, but I can't figure out how to call `sqlite3_open`

sqlite3.h contains the following definitions of `sqlite3` and `sqlite3_open`:

```
typedef struct sqlite3 sqlite3;

SQLITE_API int sqlite3_open(
  const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
  sqlite3 **ppDb          /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
);
```

Which means that sqlite3_open takes as a trailing parameter a pointer to a pointer to an anonymous structure, which seems clear enough in the tooltip:

```
func sqlite3_open(filename: CString, ppDb: CMutablePointer<COpaquePointer>) -> CInt
```

Knowing that CMutablePointer means to pass in &T, the closest I've come is:

```
class Database {
    var handle:COpaquePointer

    init(file:String) {
        let error = sqlite3_open(file as CString, &handle)
    }

    deinit {
        sqlite3_close(handle)
    }
}
```

There's no error on the sqlite3_close line, so I think I'm at least close, but the sqlite3_open line yields:

```
Cannot convert the expression's type 'CInt' to type '$T9'
```

Any clues on how to do this?

Please, no answers that say to use FMDB or other Objective-C based interfaces.  As I said, this is at least partially an exercise in figuring out how to use C libraries from swift.

Comment: What module did you import?

Comment: You don't import any module, you add sqlite3.h to your bridging headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the handle parameter, but with the string conversion.  The following works…

```
class Database {
    var handle: COpaquePointer = nil

    init(file: NSString) {
        let error = sqlite3_open(file.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), &handle)
    }
}
```

I'm unsure as to why the 'as CString' doesn't work.

Comment: To stay in swift land as long as possible I used `(file as NSString).cStringUsing...` and that seems to work, thanks!

Comment: yup, I like your solution.

Comment: Now onto the next problems, how to turn `COpaquePointer` and a length into an NSData and how to turn `UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>` into a String...

Comment: You can also use withCString() (presumably uses the platform encoding - UTF8?). Sample: file.withCString { sqlite3_open($0, &handle) }

Comment: Also: String.fromCString(up: UnsafePointer<CChar>)

Answer (score 1):

When you add `#import <sqlite3.h>` into Bridging-Header, the sqlite3 C/C++ API will be 'translated' into  native swift function. So, the `sqlite3_open` will be like below.

```
func sqlite3_open(file:String, inout ppdb:COpaquePointer) -> Int
```

And you can call this function with "String" type parameter instead of "CString". The swift compiler will translate "String" into UTF8 String data stream automatically.

```
let error = sqlite3_open(filePath, &db)
```