# Swift and Sqlite3 error when opening

Tags: swift, sqlite, ios8

my problem is that this code is giving an error of missing argument for parameter #1 at the beginning of a project:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var lineFields: [UITextField]!

    var database: COpaquePointer = nil
    var result = sqlite3_open(dataFilePath(), &database)


    if result == SQLITE3_OK {

        sqlite3_close(database)
        println("Failed to open connection")
        return
    }

    func dataFilePath() -> String {

        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectory = paths[0] as NSString
        return documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.sqlite") as String

    }
```

The var result is where the error is, could someone tell me why. I have added the libsqlite3.dylib and created the bridge needed, any help?? Thanks.
[image: Xcode pic with error]

Comment: notice that sqlite3_open takes cString not String http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109336/how-to-call-sqlite3-open-passing-opaque-pointers-by-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, sqlite3_open takes cString not String

You need to change your call to be like this:

```
var result = sqlite3_open((dataFilePath() as NSString).UTF8String, &database)
```